# Prove error bound using Taylor's series Error term (Bound doesn't seem to make sense)

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I have to prove that at least seven terms must be used in the Taylor series estimation of x - sin(x) in order for the error to be <= $10^{-9}$.  This doesn't seem correct however.  This series is equal to the summation of $\frac{-1^n * x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$  and the error term that I get for 1n = 7 doesn't even come close to $10^{-9}$

**edit**  $0 < x < 1$

Comment: What is your value for $x$? Is $|x|<1$ or something? For $x=10^{100}$ I would imagine Taylor series fails very badly...

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. updated the question. I am not given a specific value of x

Comment: When you say "seven terms" does that mean seven nonzero terms, i.e.
$x - \ldots - x^{11}/11!$, or does it mean $x - ... - x^7/7!$?

Comment: Seven nonzero terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0<x<1$, it is simplest to use the Alternating Series Test estimate for the error (although Taylor's Remainder Formula will give the same estimate):

If we use the first 5 nonzero terms of the series,

$\;\;\;\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}-\frac{x^9}{9!}+\frac{x^{11}}{11!}$,

the error satisfies  $|E|<\frac{1}{13!}<10^{-9}$ since $13!>10^9$.

(Notice that $\frac{1}{11!}>10^{-9}$, so we need at least 5 nonzero terms.)